# Leibniz determinant formula complexity

Tags: python, recursion, big-o, complexity-theory, formula

I wrote some code that calculates the determinant of a given nxn matrix using [Leibniz formula for determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants).

I am trying to figure out it's complexity in O-notation.
I think it should be something like:
`O(n!) * O(n^2) + O(n) = O(n!*n^2)` or `O((n+2)!)`
Reasoning: I think `O(n!)` is the complexity of permutations.
and `O(n)` the complexity of perm_parity, and `O(n^2)` is the multiplication of n items each iteration.

this is my code:

```
def determinant_leibnitz(self):
    assert self.dim()[0] == self.dim()[1] # O(1)
    dim = self.dim()[0] # O(1)
    det,mul = 0,1 # O(1)
    for perm in permutations([num for num in range(dim)]):
        for i in range(dim):
            mul *= self[i,perm[i]] # O(1)
        det += perm_parity(perm)*mul # O(n) ?
        mul = 1 # O(1)
    return det
```

The following functions that I wrote are also used in the calculation:

perm_parity: Given a permutation of the digits 0..n in order as a list, 
returns its parity (or sign): +1 for even parity; -1 for odd.

I think perm_parity should run at `O(n^2)` (is that correct?).

```
def perm_parity(lst):
    parity = 1
    lst = lst[:]
    for i in range(0,len(lst) - 1):
        if lst[i] != i:
            parity *= -1
            mn = argmin(lst[i:]) + i
            lst[i],lst[mn] = lst[mn],lst[i]
    return parity
```

argmin: returns the index of minimal argument in a list.
I think that argmin should run at `O(n)` (is that correct?)

```
def argmin(lst):
    return lst.index(min(lst))
```

and permutation: returns all the permutations of a given list.
e.g: input: [1,2,3], output [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]].

I think that permutations should run at `O(n!)`  (is that correct?)

```
def permutations(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return [lst]
    templst = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        part = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
        for j in permutations(part):
            templst.append(lst[i:i+1] + j)
    return templst
```

Comment: Actually it's not only `O(n!n^2)`, it's `ϴ(n!n^2)` since you always loop over all permutations and for each permutation you call `perm_parity` which does `ϴ(n^2)` operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question but still deserves an answer.

The complexity you are looking for is *`O((n+2)!)`*.
 This is since *`O(n!)`* is the complexity of this:
`for perm in permutations([num for num in range(dim)])`
*`O(n)`* the complexity of the`perm_parity` function.
*`O(n^2)`* is the complexity of multiplying `n` items in each iteration.
This all gives *`O(n!)*O(n)*O(n^2)=O(n!n^2)=O((n+2)!)`*

(And as the comment stated, in your case you also even get *`ϴ((n+2)!)`*)

Comment: Why is it O(n^2) to multiply n numbers?