# Finding determinant of a nxn matrix using Leibniz formula on python

Tags: python

I have tried to code the permutations in python. I am looking for suggestions on how to code the determinant using the Leibniz formula in python 3.7

Comment: What have you tried so far? What went wrong?

Comment: Why Leibniz's formula specifically? There are much more efficient ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use numpy, you can find the determinant using [`numpy.linalg.det()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html)

I'd recommend not using Leibniz's formula. It's not very efficient.
If you must, you can use code that I took from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527834/leibniz-determinant-formula-complexity):

```
def determinant_leibnitz(self):
    assert self.dim()[0] == self.dim()[1] # O(1)
    dim = self.dim()[0] # O(1)
    det,mul = 0,1 # O(1)
    for perm in permutations([num for num in range(dim)]):
        for i in range(dim):
            mul *= self[i,perm[i]] # O(1)
        det += perm_parity(perm)*mul # O(n) ?
        mul = 1 # O(1)
    return det
```

Where the nested functions are defined as such:

```
def perm_parity(lst):
    parity = 1
    lst = lst[:]
    for i in range(0,len(lst) - 1):
        if lst[i] != i:
            parity *= -1
            mn = argmin(lst[i:]) + i
            lst[i],lst[mn] = lst[mn],lst[i]
    return parity 

def argmin(lst):
    return lst.index(min(lst))

def permutations(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return [lst]
    templst = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        part = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
        for j in permutations(part):
            templst.append(lst[i:i+1] + j)
    return templst
```

Answer (score 0):

One can compute the permutation parity simultaneously with generating permutations using Python's own code (which is in C but the Pythonic description is still available there) with a very small parity addition:

```
#https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
  pool = tuple(iterable)
  n = len(pool)
  r = n if r is None else r
  if r > n: return
  indices = list(range(n))
  cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
  parity = 0
  yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r]), parity
  while n:
    for i in reversed(range(r)):
      cycles[i] -= 1
      if cycles[i] == 0:
        if ((n-i) & 1) == 0: parity = 1 - parity
        indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
        cycles[i] = n - i
      else:
        j = cycles[i]
        parity, indices[i], indices[-j] = 1 - parity, indices[-j], indices[i]
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r]), parity
        break
    else: return
def determinant(mat):
  import functools
  n = len(mat)
  print(list(permutations(range(n))))
  def dosign(parity, x): return -x if parity else x
  return sum(dosign(parity, functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, (mat[i][sigma[i]] for i in range(n)))) for sigma, parity in permutations(range(n)))
print(determinant([[-2, -1, 2], [2, 1, 4], [-3, 3, -1]]))
```

Nearly a one-liner for the actual determinant computation :).